# How to perform the delete method in drf django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How to perform the delete request in Django drf? How will I pass the params for the request?
Kindly help with the solution. I am very new in this *drf-django-python* programming.

```
class DeleteView(APIView):
    def delete(self, request,format=None):
        id = request.POST['book_id']
        email = request.POST['email']
        book = models.Book.objects.filter(book_id=id)
        book_uploader = serializers.BookSerializer(book[0]).data['uploader']['email']
        logged_in = request.user
        print(log)
        if book_uploader == logged_in :

            books = models.BookUserRelationship.objects.filter(book= id, user__email=email)

            books.delete()
            return Response("Successfully removed", status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
        else :
            return Response("Not able to remove")
```

Comment: It depends on your view class and implementation. Can you show your view class?

Comment: edited the question

Comment: Can you please help me with the solution

Comment: How you want to send book_id and email ? Query params or embedded in url or as post data ?

Comment: to be embedded in url

Comment: Can you pls suggest a solution so as to perform the delete function with the params embedded in url?

Comment: Embedding email in the URL is an odd thing to do. But sending the parameters for a delete request is exactly the same as for any other request. Have you done the basic Django tutorial?

Comment: Yeah I have gone through the basic django tutorial. Almost tried all the possible solutions. Is it the same as of other requests?

Comment: I have edited the question. Can you pls suggest any solution

Answer (score 0):

In comments you noticed that parameters will be embedded in url but you are trying to get values from POST dict.

If your url is something like

> /books/id/email/

You should use **request.kwargs** dict like **request.kwargs.get('email')**

But if your url is like

> /books/id/?email=someemail@google.com

**id** would be in **request.kwargs** but **email** in **request.query_params**

Notice that every url variable is in the **request.query_params** dict.

**IMPORTANT**

If you have ID url param without named group, viewset would not be able to get this from **request.kwargs** by name